# string variable to turn to an integer variable

Tags: bash

I have the following issue.

I'm putting a string into a variable , `$var1`. This string will be a numeric type e.g. `118`.

I did the following command line to fill my variable:

```
var1=$(cat test.html | grep "<quote")
```

But when I'm putting the variable into the loop below ...

```
for page in {1..$var1} ; do
 wget "http://www.hellomovie.co.uk/movies/decade-2000/year-2001/?page=$page";
 done
```

The wget is getting me this ...

```
Saved in : «index.html@page={1..118}»

[ <=> ] 135 284 --.-K/s   in 0,1s 2014-04-08 15:36:58 (1,07 MB/ - «index.html@page=**{1..118}**.2» saved[135284]`
```

As you can see, the variable was not taken into account.

I tried the following to make sure that `$var1` was seen as a numeric variable , `$(($var1))` but to no avail.

I tried `expr` but to no avail as well.

Did I do something wrong? If yes, can you pintpoint me where?

Any insights will be welcomed.

Cheers.

Comment: If the file contains *just* the number, you can get it more efficiently with `read var1 < test.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Chepner. Alas, the file is a html file with many things. I needed `sed` to remove many things. But I will keep it , for later usage. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** use variable as in `{1..$N}`.

Use BASH arithmetic construct i.e. `((...))`:

```
for ((page=1; page<=var1; page++)); do
```

Comment: Cheers Anubhava. You are my savior. :)

Comment: Everything inside `((...))` is evaluated in an arithmetic context, so the dollar sign is optional. Anything that doesn't look like a number or an operator is assumed to be a variable and expanded (to 0, if the variable wasn't previously set).

Comment: Indeed Chepner. I tried without the dollar as well and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
for page in `seq $var1` ; do
...
...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(( page=1 ; page <= $var1 ; page++)); do
 wget "http://www.hellomovie.co.uk/movies/decade-2000/year-2001/?page=$page";
done
```

You're problem wasn't in assigning the variable, but trying to use `$var1` inside of the `{ .. }` construct.